# Is HTML Canvas quadraticCurveTo() not exact?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, line, intersection, bezier

Edit: I just changed my Control Point to the Intersection. That's why it couldn't fit anymore.

I know it's a very presumptuous. But I am working on a Web-Application and I need to calculate the intersection with a quadratic Beziere-Curve and a Line.

- Linear Bezier-Curve: `P=s(W-V)+V`
- Quadratic Bezier-Curve: `P=t²(A-2B+C)+t(-2A+2B)+A`

Because `W`, `V`, `A`, `B`, and `C` are points, I could make two equation. I rearranged the first equation to seperate s to solve the equation.
I'm pretty sure i did it correctly, but my intersection was not on the line. So i was wondering and made my own quadratic-Beziercurve by the correct formular and my intersection hits this curve. Now I am wondering what did I wrong?

That is my function:

```js
intersectsWithLineAtT(lineStartPoint, lineEndPoint)
{
    let result = []
    let A = this.startPoint, B = this.controlPoint, C = this.endPoint, V = lineStartPoint, W = lineEndPoint
    if (!Common.isLineIntersectingLine(A, B, V, W)
        && !Common.isLineIntersectingLine(B, C, V, W)
        && !Common.isLineIntersectingLine(A, C, V, W))
        return null

    let alpha = Point.add(Point.subtract(A, Point.multiply(B, 2)), C)
    let beta = Point.add(Point.multiply(A, -2), Point.multiply(B, 2))
    let gamma = A
    let delta = V
    let epsilon = Point.subtract(W, V)

    let a = alpha.x * (epsilon.y / epsilon.x) - alpha.y
    let b = beta.x * (epsilon.y / epsilon.x) - beta.y
    let c = (gamma.x - delta.x) * (epsilon.y / epsilon.x) - gamma.y + delta.y

    let underSquareRoot = b * b - 4 * a * c

    if (Common.compareFloats(0, underSquareRoot))
        result.push(-b / 2 * a)
    else if (underSquareRoot > 0)
    {
        result.push((-b + Math.sqrt(underSquareRoot)) / (2 * a))
        result.push((-b - Math.sqrt(underSquareRoot)) / (2 * a))
    }

    result = result.filter((t) =>
    {
        return (t >= 0 && t <= 1)
    })

    return result.length > 0 ? result : null
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Lena

Answer (score 1):

The curve/line intersection problem is the same as the root finding problem, after we rotate all coordinates such that the line ends up on top of the x-axis:

[image]

which involves a quick trick involving [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2):

```
const d = W.minus(V);
const angle = -atan2(d.y, d.x);
const rotated = [A,B,C].map(p => p.minus(V).rotate(angle));
```

Assuming you're working with point classes that understand vector operations. If not, easy enough to do with standard `{x, y}` objects:

```
const rotated = [A,B,C].map(p => {
  p.x -= V.x;
  p.y -= V.y;
  return {
    x: p.x * cos(a) - p.y * sin(a),
    y: p.x * sin(a) + p.y * cos(a)
  };
});
```

Then all we need to find out is which `t` values yield `y=0`, which is (as you also used) just applying the quadratic formula. And we don't need to bother with collapsing dimensions: we've reduced the problem to finding solutions in just the `y` dimension, so taking

```
const a = rotated[0].y;
const b = rotated[1].y;
const c = rotated[2].y;
```

and combining that with the fact that we know that `Py = t²(a-b+c)+t(-2a+2b)+a` we just work out that `t = -b/2a +/- sqrt(b² - 4ac))/2a` with the usual checks for negative, zero, and positive discriminant, as well as checking for division by  zero.

This gives us with zero or more `t` value(s) for the y=0 intercept in our rotated case, and for the intersection between our curve and line in the unrotated case. No additional calculations required. Aside from "evaluating B(t) to get the actual (x,y) cooordinates", of course.

Comment: Oh my god, I am embarrassed! Your answer was very helpfull Mike, but in an other way. Somehow i did a mistake in your calculation and i recognized that even my Curve changed the way of it's look. So there was no mistake in my calculation, I just changed my controlPoint to the Intersection. So it couldn't fit anymore! But I am really thankful for your answer, because it gave me an other way of calculating. <3

Comment: That's the nice thing about Bezier curves. As something that has meaningful geometric, algebraic, and calculus expressions and interpretations, there's many ways to achieve the same thing.